# Three.js Auto rotate camera to focus on object

Tags: javascript, three.js

In three.js 3D space, I have some MESH objects for which its positions are known and a camera object.

What I would like to achieve is: when I click on a button, the camera will auto-rotate and zoom (change its position) so that the user's view will focus on the selected object. The selected object's position is known.

Please give me some suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Try `camera.lookAt( object.position );`

You don't need to use quaternions.

You can then move the camera closer if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But seems that wouldn't make a smooth transition of the camera to the object. I think that it should be something about changing the camera position because when rotating camera with mouse, it is updating the camera position to new one based on the mouse params

Comment: You did not mention anything about "smooth transition" in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Quaternion slerp is your friend for smooth rotations to target location. You need to use quaternion (camera.useQuaternion = true).

```
var newQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
THREE.Quaternion.slerp(camera.quaternion, destinationQuaternion, newQuaternion, 0.07);
camera.quaternion = newQuaternion;
```

This should smoothly rotate to the destination rotation. Maybe you need to play around with the last parameter. I'm not sure about zoom.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. About the paraneters, is it the destinationQuaternion is targetObject.quaternion? Does the "newQuaternion" parameter need anymore specification? I try the following but it does not work. `var newQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    THREE.Quaternion.slerp(camera.quaternion, targetObj.quaternion, newQuaternion, 0.07);
    camera.quaternion = newQuaternion;` Do you have a exmaple or demo about this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet for rotating an object using slerp and quaternions:

```
//Initial and final quaternions
var startQ = new THREE.Quaternion(0,0,0,1);
var endQ = new THREE.Quaternion(0,1,0,0);

//Number of animation frames
var animFrames = 100;
//Pause between two consecutive animation frames
var deltaT = 1;
function goSlerping(acc) {
      if(acc>=1) return;

      //Let's assume that you want to rotate a 3D object named 'mesh'. So:
      THREE.Quaternion.slerp(startQ, endQ, mesh.quaternion, acc);
      setTimeout(function() {
          goSlerping(acc + (1/animFrames));
      }, deltaT);
}
goSlerping(1/animFrames);
```

So using the above script to rotate camera is quite the same: you just need to change `mesh.quaternion` with `camera.quaternion`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to visit here...
https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-cameras.html
I did the following and worked for me to get the focus on user-defined coordinate...

```
camera.lookAt(0, 10, 0);
-----
-----
-----
controls.target.set(0, 10, 0);
controls.update();
```